# Unable to implement Google Map API without creating abstract class

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Learning Java programming from Big Nerd Ranch, I'm trying to develop a simple app leveraging on Google Map API but I encounter an error saying 'MapsActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onConnectionSuspended(int) in ConnectionCallbacks'. Abstract class doesn't seem to be the way to go as component cannot be instantiated.

```
package com.example.test.empower;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.Manifest;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    TextView textView_location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        textView_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_location);
        // Font Awesome for Location Icon
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fa_regular_400.ttf" );
        TextView fa_map_marker = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.map_marker);
        fa_map_marker.setTypeface(font);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        textView_location.setText("First");
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // Create array of permission
        String mPerms[] = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        // Checks for permission
        if(checkSelfPermission(mPerms[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            requestPermissions(mPerms, 1);

        }
        else {
            // Enable Location
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);

            if(mLastLocation != null){
                double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("You're here."));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
                mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 12.0f ) );
                textView_location.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/round_alert_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_alert_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/handshake_100x66"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:text="Get Assistance"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="Proxima Nova"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <com.example.denise.empower.FontAwesome
        android:id="@+id/map_marker"
        android:text="@string/fa_map_marker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:text="Singapore"
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:fontFamily="Proxima Nova"
        android:textStyle=""
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_description"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:text="Do not subject yourself to a silent victim, reach out to our nearest law-enforcer."
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:fontFamily="Proxima Nova"
        android:textStyle=""
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`GoogleMapsApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` is an [`interface`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) with two abstract methods: `onConnected()` and `onConnectionSuspended()`. Because you are implementing the `interface`, you must either implement both these methods or declare your class `abstract` to indicate that a sub-class will do the implementation.

As you mentioned, you're doing the actual implementation, so abstract is not the way to go. Somewhere in your class you have to override `onConnectionSuspended()`. If you don't plan on using that callback, just leave the body of the method empty, but the declaration must be contained within your class.